# Get rid of loud pops from audio

Tags: audio, audio-quality, noise-reduction

This is more related to audio than video so I apologize if I posted in the wrong forum. I've prerecorded some podcasts to listen on long drives/flights/trains and for the most part things have been great. I also run them through a normalizer to make sure the sound volume is consistent.

However, some audio files have an occasional pop that goes way above the normal volume and hurts my ears. Since I listen to the audio in my headphones, this is much worse than if my speaker made that noise.

I've tried googling about this but couldn't find much info, so maybe I'm not using the correct name for this phenomenon, it's basically a sudden, loud, and sharp sound that sounds like a balloon popping inside of my head. I was hoping I could use something like Audacity to detect and get rid of it - because detecting them with my own ears doesn't seem to be working too well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Audacity for this purpose, and you can follow this link to learn how: http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_click_and_pop_removal_techniques.html

Generally, clicks are little bursts of noise (such as a small scratch on a vinyl record), and pops are larger bursts of noise (such as a large scratch or a plosive "P" hitting a microphone without a pop filter).